# Using Euler's Formula to prove $\sin^32x\cos^23x = -\frac1{16}(\sin12x-3\sin8x+2\sin6x+3\sin 4x-6\sin 2x) $

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am asked to show the following using Euler's formula, but I cannot see, how this relates to Euler's formula.

$$
\sin^32x\cos^23x = -\frac{1}{16}(\sin 12x - 3\sin 8x + 2\sin 6x + 3\sin 4x - 6\sin 2x)
$$

Comment: Maybe you could remind us what Euler's method is?

Comment: I guess you mean [Euler's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula), not Euler's method.

Comment: For the record, an alternative would be to write $$\sin^3(2x)\cos^2(3x)=\left(\frac{3\sin(2x)-\sin(6x)}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1+\cos(6x)}{2}\right)$$ and then product-to-sum identities.

Comment: By the way, your formula is not correct, it should be 
$$
\sin^3(2x)\cos^2(3x) = \color{red}{-}\frac{1}{16}(\sin 12x - 3\sin 8x + 2\sin 6x + 3\sin 4x - 6\sin 2x)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Euler the left hand side is 
$$
\left(\frac{\zeta^2-\zeta^{-2}}{2i}\right)^3
\left(\frac{\zeta^3+\zeta^{-3}}{2}\right)^2
$$
where $\zeta:=e^{ix}$.
It is easy to multiply this out and identify every term on the right hand side.